# can you add a value as the relationship type from the csv

Tags: neo4j

eg [:owes] instead of this i would like the amount they owe (row.amount)

couldnt come up with much

Comment: You might be able to do it using APOC functions, not plain cypher.

Comment: could you help with the code required for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below simple cypher script will load the csv file then create a relationship type based on the row.amount and uses APOC (awesome procedure)

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///testing.csv" AS row
MERGE (p:Person {name: row.fromPerson})
MERGE (m:Person {name: row.toPerson})
WITH p, m, row
CALL apoc.create.relationship(p, row.amount, {amount: row.amount}, m) YIELD rel
RETURN p, m, rel;
```

Sample testing.csv:

```
fromPerson,amount,toPerson
"Tom Hanks",100,"Meg Ryan"
```

Sample Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to have this as relationship type. The standard way of storing such information is to keep the `OWES` label as a type and store the amount value as relationship property.

Example statement :

```
LOAD CSV FROM file:///... AS row
MERGE (from:User {id: row.from_id})
MERGE (to:User {id: row.to_id})
MERGE (from)-[r:OWES]->(to)
SET r.amount = row.amount
```

If for visualisation purposes you want to see the amount as the caption for the relationship in the Neo4j browser, you can do the following.

1. Click on the relationship type in the panel on the right
2. Select the property you want to use as caption

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you help with the code for this "The standard way of storing such information is to keep the OWES label as a type and store the amount value as relationship property."

Comment: added in the answer